# Why won't my electric baseboard heaters work?

Tags: electrical, heating

I'm installing a 72" 240V baseboard heater in a home office. I ran 12/2 gauge wire, installed a 20 amp 2-pole breaker and 2-pole thermostat. I'm pretty good with electrical, and so I can confirm that all is connected properly. Yet I have no heat. I tested the line at the breaker, and I have 120V at each leg. All grounds are connected but no heat. If I take my probe and touch each screw on the breaker I have nothing. I thought I should have 240V on the tester.

What is happening and how do I fix it?

Comment: What kind of panel is it?

Comment: Hi Speedy! its a SquareD

Comment: Are you sure you used a two-pole breaker and not a twin breaker?

Comment: Well, that just may be it. How can I tell the difference? The breaker im using is a double breaker, with a clip holding both switches. would this be just a ganged 20 or a true 240v breaker?

Comment: Two side by side, that takes up two spaces, should be a two-pole breaker. A twin breaker is one space wide and has two toggles (sometimes side-by side, sometimes in-line.) You should indeed have 240V from hot to hot (L1 to L2) of a double breaker... Hmm. I wonder if this might be the QO is not Homeline issue with square-D panels (not all Square-D breakers are the same.)

Comment: the panel certainly is home line, the breaker does take up 2 spaces. Ive exchanged the heaters and thermostats 3 times, and the breakers twice thinking they may be defective, theyre not. im just at a loss here.

Comment: Does everything else in your home work? It really seems like one leg of the panel is dead, but if everything is OK that is impossible.

Comment: So it seems i discovered what the problem is. my panel has a jumper on the positive side (black wire) making both blades in the panel hot. the white is on the neutral bar. I wired the heater, 120v and it worked. i dont know enough to correct this so it will stay like this for now. in the future, what will have to happen to allow me to get 240v current? thanks Speedy and Ecnerwal for your comments.

Comment: You should have two hots coming from your meter, along with the neutral. This is 120V on each hot, 180 degrees out of phase. As you seem to know using both hots gives you 240V. It sounds like you're saying you're only getting one 120V leg from the meter and this is connected to both sides of your breaker box. You seem to have 120V service, not 240V service. It'd be interesting if you'd post a photo showing the jumper. Meanwhile, you need to call an electrician and/or your electric supplier.

Comment: Is this the main service panel in the home, or a panel fed from the main service panel?  How many wires are feeding the panel?

Comment: Ok PeteO Lift wires off breaker and test again? you are getting backfeed thru the heater to the breaker. If there is not a problem on any of your other 240v circuits, your 2pole 20 is probably bad,

Answer (score 1):

Right. I've seen this before. Some handyman put in a subpanel, but only ran 120V service to it (who knows why - saving money on wires? Expanding one wire feeding an outlet into a whole sub-panel?) and then jumpers the hots - which works OK if everything is 120V loads - which was probably the case when the panel was installed.

This does, of course, mean that a 2-pole breaker has pretty much 0 volts across it, as both sides are fed from the same phase (both are 120V to neutral/&ground.)

You'll need to add another hot wire from the source to the panel (traditionally red in the US system - black hot, red hot, white neutral (grounded), green or bare safety ground.)

Depending what the current wiring is, and especially if it's inappropriately sized (which would go right along with the handyman's decision to run it 120V) it may be more appropriate to replace the current wiring completely with 4 wire cable (called 3-wire cable due to the convention of not counting the ground wire) or 4 wires in conduit.

I'd also double-check the status of the ground and neutral - in a sub-panel the neutral is supposed to be isolated from the ground (including not being connected to the case, which should be grounded) and I would not bet on that being how this one is, just following the pattern of behavior shown by whoever wired it up.

You should probably go over the whole electrical system looking for any other "interesting" work that's been done to it, and possibly call in an electrician to check you on anything you can't sort out. *Incidentally (clarifying my comment), both QO and Homeline are fine, it's just that the breakers have to be the same flavor as the panel, and sometimes folks get the wrong one as both are Square-D products, and they almost-sort-of fit. But that has nothing to do with your problem, from your description in the comments.*